# How to compare Time in MySQLi query when time is in type Varchar

Tags: php, mysqli

How to compare time only, where time is stored like **09:00 AM** in a varchar field. there are two times, starttime and endtime.  i want to display all the records in between specific times which comes from user input. for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `starttime` > '09:00 AM' AND `endtime` < '05:00 PM'
```

What i have already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME_FORMAT( `starttime`, "%h:%i %p" ) > '09:00 AM' 

AND

TIME_FORMAT( `endtime`, "%h:%i %p" ) < '02:30 PM'
```

basic database structure is like this

```
CREATE TABLE table
(`id` int, `date` DATE, `location` varchar(55),`starttime` varchar(55),
`endtime` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO table
(`id`, `date`, `location`,`starttime`,`endtime`)
VALUES
(1, '2015-01-01', 'rnd','02:00 PM','04:00 PM'),
(2, '2015-01-10' ,'rnd','09:00 AM','02:00 PM'),
(3, '2015-01-03', 'rnd','03:00 PM','04:30 PM'),
(4, '2015-01-04', 'rnd','09:00 AM','05:30 PM'),
(5, '2015-01-05', 'rnd','11:00 AM','01:30 PM'),
(6, '2015-01-02', 'rnd','08:00 AM','01:30 PM'),
(7, '2015-01-03', 'rnd','10:00 AM','09:30 PM')
;
```

Now when i run query with starttime > '09:00 AM' AND endtime < '05:00 PM' the
query should return 1, 3 , 5 row.

Comment: I think the better way to approach this is to make your `starttime` column a `timestamp` and then just compare normally.  You can still display things like `09:00 AM` using the appropriate output functions, but internally you would be storing a timestamp.

Comment: can you please provide an example? thanks!

Comment: Just do it the other way round. Don't cast everything to text before doing maths, cast everything to time.

Comment: problem i cannot change the database, if you could give an example query that would be very helpful.